# Tagging text and reverse index of tags?

Tags: dictionaries

Given some text, I would like to tag various passages as belonging to one or more categories, and produce a reverse list of such passages, itemized by their tags (see below, and see comments for 2nd version with addition of named `tagging` environment, allowing for multiple indices).

---

Ideally, a command such as `\tag[tag1,tag2,...]{this is the text}` would be used to associate a portion of the text with one or more tags.

As an example, let the first paragraph of Cervantes' Don Quixote (1605) be tagged as follows (contents are irrelevant).

\resettags[mytags]

En un lugar de \tag[place]{la Mancha}, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de \tag[weapon]{lanza} en astillero, \tag[weapon]{adarga} antigua, \tag[animal]{rocín} flaco y \tag[animal]{galgo corredor}. Una \tag[food]{olla} de algo más \tag[food,animal]{vaca} que \tag[food,animal]{carnero}, \tag[food]{salpicón} las más noches, \tag[food]{duelos y quebrantos} los \tag[day]{sábados}, \tag[food]{lantejas} los \tag[day]{viernes}, algún \tag[food,animal]{palomino} de añadidura los \tag[day]{domingos}, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda.

\maketags[mytags]

---

The `\maketags[<tag index>]` command would compute and insert the reverse tag index. Given the above I would get:

### Tag Index

**animal**: carnero; galgo; palomino; rocín; vaca.

**day**: domingos; sábados; viernes.

**food**: duelos y quebrantos; lantejas; olla; palomino; salpicon; vaca; carnero.

**place**: la Mancha.

**weapon**: adarga; lanza.

---

Note: tags and entries under each tag are ordered alphabetically, and the separator is ";". These could be default options, to change one could do `\maketags[name=mytags,sort=false,sep=|]`

---

Update: the design has slightly evolved/converged to the usage shown below:

```
\usepackage[tagsmult] % loads .sty

\begin{document}

... 

\begin{tagging}[txt1]
... \tag{tag1}{text snippet} ...
... \tag{tag1,tag2}{text snippet} ...
... \tag{tag3}{text snippet} ...
\end{tagging}

... 

\begin{tagging}[txt2]
... tagged text 2
\end{tagging}

...

\begin{tagging}[txt1] % note reuse of 'txt1'
... tagged text 3
\end{tagging}

...

\section*{Txt1 Index}

\maketags[txt1] % combines two 'txt1' blocks

\section*{Txt2 Index}

\maketags[txt2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer using LaTeX3 and expl3. I've changed some of your syntax to be more standard for LaTeX, though it could be changed back pretty easily. Also note that this conflicts with `amsmath` tag, so you might want to change the name if you want to use both.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Create a new command with no arguments that creates and clears the tag index
\NewDocumentCommand{\resettags}{}{%
  \prop_gclear_new:N \tag_index_prop
}

% Create a new command with two (m)andatory arguments, the tag(s) and the text
\NewDocumentCommand{\tag}{mm}{%
  % Preserve the text
  #2
  % Split the tags up into a temporary sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {,} {#1}
  % Loop through the tags
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    % Check if the tag has been created yet
    \prop_get:NnNTF \tag_index_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl {% 
      % If already created
      % Add the text to the tag index as a comma separated value
      \prop_put:Nnx \tag_index_prop {##1} { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl,#2 }
    } {%
      % If not yet created
      % Set the tag's value in the index to the text
      \prop_put:Nnn \tag_index_prop {##1} { #2 }
    }
  }
}

% Create a new command with one (o)ptional argument, the options for the command
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketags}{O{}}{%
  % Define options for make tags
  \keys_define:nn {make_tags_module}
  {
    sort .bool_set:N = \tag_sort_keys_bool,
    sort .initial:n = true,
    sep .tl_set:N = \tag_word_sep_tl,
    sep .initial:n = ;\ ,
  }
  % Read in options
  \keys_set:nn {make_tags_module} { #1 }

  % Turn the keys of the tag index into a seq for sorting
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \tag_index_prop {%
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1}
  }

  % Check if should sort
  \bool_if:NTF \tag_sort_keys_bool {%
    % Sort the tags in alphabetical order
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      % You can use \str_compare:nNnTF here, but it wasn't in my distribution
      \int_compare:nTF {\pdfstrcmp{##1}{##2} < 0} 
      { \sort_return_same: } 
      { \sort_return_swapped: }
    }
  } {}

  % Print each tag
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    % Get the words
    \prop_get:NnN \tag_index_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
    % Split the words by comma
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpb_seq {,} \l_tmpa_tl
    % Check if should sort
    \bool_if:NTF \tag_sort_keys_bool {%
      % Sort the words in alphabetical order
      \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {%
        \int_compare:nTF {\pdfstrcmp{####1}{####2} < 0} 
        { \sort_return_same: } 
        { \sort_return_swapped: }
      }
    } {}
    % Print
    \noindent\textbf{##1}:\ \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\tag_word_sep_tl} \par
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It would be used like so:

```
\begin{document}

\resettags

En un lugar de \tag{place}{la Mancha}, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de \tag{weapon}{lanza} en astillero, \tag{weapon}{adarga} antigua, \tag{animal}{rocín} flaco y \tag{animal}{galgo} corredor. Una \tag{food}{olla} de algo más \tag{food,animal}{vaca} que \tag{food,animal}{carnero}, \tag{food}{salpicón} las más noches, \tag{food}{duelos y quebrantos} los \tag{day}{sábados}, \tag{food}{lantejas} los \tag{day}{viernes}, algún \tag{food,animal}{palomino} de añadidura los \tag{day}{domingos}, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda.

\maketags
% or
\maketags[sep={,}\ ]
% or
\maketags[sort=false, sep=-]

\end{document}
```

Which renders more or less exactly like you showed in your question. Hope this helps!

---

Edit: Added support for named indices, and made it into an environment, as discussed in the comments.
Edit 2: Fixed naming and made tags merge.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Create a new command with no arguments that creates and clears the tag index
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tagged}{o}{%
  \prop_gclear_new:N \g__tag_index_prop
}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{%
    \prop_if_exist:cTF {g__tag_index_#1_prop} {
      % If it already exists, merge
      \prop_map_inline:Nn \g__tag_index_prop {
        \prop_get:cnNTF {g__tag_index_#1_prop} { ##1 } \l_tmpa_tl {
          % Merge
          \prop_gput:cno {g__tag_index_#1_prop} { \l_tmpa_tl, ##2 }
        } {
          % Add
          \prop_gput:cnn {g__tag_index_#1_prop} { ##1 } { ##2 }
        }
      }
    } {
      % If it doesn't exist, just copy everything over
      \prop_new:c {g__tag_index_#1_prop}
      \prop_gset_eq:cN {g__tag_index_#1_prop} \g__tag_index_prop
    }
  }
}

% Create a new command with two (m)andatory arguments, the tag(s) and the text
\NewDocumentCommand{\tag}{mm}{%
  % Preserve the text
  #2
  % Split the tags up into a temporary sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {,} {#1}
  % Loop through the tags
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    % Check if the tag has been created yet
    \prop_get:NnNTF \g__tag_index_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl {% 
      % If already created
      % Add the text to the tag index as a comma separated value
      \prop_gput:Nno \g__tag_index_prop {##1} { \l_tmpa_tl, #2 }
    } {%
      % If not yet created
      % Set the tag's value in the index to the text
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g__tag_index_prop {##1} { #2 }
    }
  }
}

% Create a new command with one (o)ptional argument, the options for the command
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketags}{O{}}{%
  % Define options for make tags
  \keys_define:nn {make_tags_module}
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \tag_name_tl,
    name .initial:n =,
    sort .bool_set:N = \tag_sort_bool,
    sort .initial:n = true,
    sep .tl_set:N = \tag_word_sep_tl,
    sep .initial:n = ;\ ,
  }
  % Read in options
  \keys_set:nn {make_tags_module} { #1 }

  \tl_if_empty:NTF \tag_name_tl {
    \prop_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_prop \g__tag_index_prop  
  } {
    \prop_set_eq:Nc \l_tmpa_prop {g__tag_index_ \tag_name_tl _prop}
  }

  % Turn the keys of the tag index into a seq for sorting
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {%
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1}
  }

  % Check if should sort
  \bool_if:NTF \tag_sort_bool {%
    % Sort the tags in alphabetical order
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      % You can use \str_compare:nNnTF here, but it wasn't in my distribution
      \int_compare:nTF {\pdfstrcmp{##1}{##2} < 0} 
      { \sort_return_same: } 
      { \sort_return_swapped: }
    }
  } {}

  % Print each tag
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    % Get the words
    \prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
    % Split the words by comma
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpb_seq {,} \l_tmpa_tl
    % Check if should sort
    \bool_if:NTF \tag_sort_bool {%
      % Sort the words in alphabetical order
      \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {%
        \int_compare:nTF {\pdfstrcmp{####1}{####2} < 0} 
        { \sort_return_same: } 
        { \sort_return_swapped: }
      }
    } {}
    % Print
    \noindent\textbf{##1}:\ \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\tag_word_sep_tl} \par
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tagged}[sec1]
  En un lugar de \tag{place}{la Mancha}, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de \tag{weapon}{lanza} en astillero, \tag{weapon}{adarga} antigua, \tag{animal}{rocín} flaco y \tag{animal}{galgo} corredor. Una \tag{food}{olla} de algo más \tag{food,animal}{vaca} que \tag{food,animal}{carnero}, \tag{food}{salpicón} las más noches, \tag{food}{duelos y quebrantos} los \tag{day}{sábados}, \tag{food}{lantejas} los \tag{day}{viernes}, algún \tag{food,animal}{palomino} de añadidura los \tag{day}{domingos}, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda.
\end{tagged}

\begin{tagged}[sec2]
  \tag{test}{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis \tag{test2}{aute} irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \tag{test}{fugiat} nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{tagged}

\begin{tagged}[sec1]
  \tag{test}{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis \tag{test2}{aute} irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \tag{test}{fugiat} nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{tagged}

% by default prints the previous if no name is given
\maketags
%or
\maketags[name=sec1]
% or
\maketags[name=sec2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Kevin, can't wait to try it out. You are a godsend!

Comment: I have one crucial request: can you make the \resettags[name] and \maketags[name] accept an optional index name, allowing several tag indices in the same document. E.g.:

\resettags[hello1]

... first tagged text ...

\resettags[hello2]

... tagged text 2 ...

% two reverse indices here

\maketags[hello1]

\maketags[hello2]

Another option (perhaps more efficient) is to surround the tagged region with

\begin{tagging}[name] ... \end{tagging}

Comment: @DanReznik I'll see what I can do, but if you want to try to add that yourself, it would basically just be turning the \resettags macro into the tagging environment, and having it save the tag index into a specifically named variable at the end (maybe `\tag_index_#1_prop`), which could then be selected in maketags.

Comment: Thanks. I am very grateful for your help. I have zero training in the latex programming language.

Comment: @DanReznik I added support for named tag indices in the edit above, hope it helps! Btw if this answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the solution. Have a nice day!

Comment: Very nice! This looks like the beginning of a new and very useful package.

Comment: Kevin, thanks, marked as brilliant solution! Absolutely genius! Now you are going into my book's acknowledgements.

Comment: @DanReznik Haha sounds good, you should let me know when you publish it so I can see XD

Comment: Kevin one last *crucial* request: the current code does not support more than one \begin{tagging}[name1] ... \end{tagging} "environment" with the *same* name; could you alter the code so the index is *not* reset if a second tagging environment with a previously used name is used? this would allow for non-contiguous portions of the document to contribute to a single named reverse tag index...

Comment: so I could do: \begin{tagging}[name1] <text1> \end{tagging} ... \begin{tagging}[name2] <text2> \end{tagging} ... \begin{tagging}[name1] <text3> \end{tagging} \maketags[name1] % this would *combine* the tags in <text1> and <text3>, as you know, it currently only reports the tags in <text3>.

Comment: @DanReznik I added that + a minor fix to expansion above, lmk how it works (its the same place as the last edit, I think if I add any more code blocks its going to be too long haha)

Comment: Just tested it, ready, set, go!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In OpTeX, we can solve this task by following macros:

```
\def\tags{}
\def\tag[#1]#2{\foreach#1,\do##1,{\unskip
   \ifcsname tag:##1\endcsname \ea\addto\csname tag:##1\endcsname{{#2}}%
   \else \sdef{tag:##1}{{#2}}\ea\addto\ea\tags\ea{\csname tag:##1\endcsname}%
   \fi
}}
\def\sort #1\endsort {\def\slist{}\tmpnum=0
   \foreach #1\do
      {\ifx.##1\else \incr\tmpnum 
       \ea\addto\ea\slist\ea{\csname+##1\endcsname}%
       \sdef{+##1}{##1}\fi
      }
   \_dosorting\slist
   \ea\foreach \slist \do{\decr\tmpnum ##1\ifnum\tmpnum=0.\else; \fi}%
}
\def\maketags{%
   \_dosorting\tags
   \ea \xargs \ea \newitem \tags ;
}
\def\newitem #1{\par \noindent \ea\tagname\string#1; 
   \ea\sort #1.\endsort
}
\def\tagname#1:#2;{{\bf#2}:}

%% test:

En un lugar de \tag[place]{la Mancha}, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de \tag[weapon]{lanza} en astillero, \tag[weapon]{adarga} antigua, \tag[animal]{rocín} flaco y \tag[animal]{galgo corredor}. Una \tag[food]{olla} de algo más \tag[food,animal]{vaca} que \tag[food,animal]{carnero}, \tag[food]{salpicón} las más noches, \tag[food]{duelos y quebrantos} los \tag[day]{sábados},
\tag[food]{lantejas} los \tag[day]{viernes}, algún
\tag[food,animal]{palomino} de añadidura los \tag[day]{domingos}, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda.

\bigskip

\maketags

\bye
```

Comment: very interesting too, let me try it.

Comment: Kevin is it possible to add an extra "lookup table" argument to \maketags[] so that the tags would be replaced by the table when spat out? e.g., assume I have tags "place", and "food", as above, but I issued: 
\maketags[name=blabla1,lookup={place=loc,food=eat}]  
this would cause the header to the 'place:' list to be printed as 'loc:' (still in boldface) and that of the 'food:" tag to be printed as 'eat:', with all others preserved. is this feasible?

Comment: @DanReznik Please, be more specific. The alphabetic sorting must be done by what? By the original words or by the substitutions?

Comment: Hi! The sorting should be done by the substitutions (i.e., new tags), and those should be the ones shown as boldfaced headers. Does it make sense?